# Wrong output from dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

Why do I get output of my namespace.object when printing from dictionary?

This is my data object.

```
namespace MoleCalculator
{
    public class elementDO
    {
        public int AtomicNumber { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal AtomicWeight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the class that has my dictionary

```
namespace MoleCalculator
{
public class elementDictionary
{
    public Dictionary<int, elementDO> periodic_Table = new Dictionary<int, elementDO>()
    {
        {1,new elementDO{AtomicNumber = 1,Symbol = "H",Name = "Hydrogen", AtomicWeight = 1.007825M}},
```

This is what drives it

```
var elements = new elementDictionary().periodic_Table;
        Console.WriteLine(elements[1]);
```

Comment: you have to override `ToString`.

Comment: The default string representation of an object is the type name of that object.  .NET has no way of knowing how you personally imagine your object should be printed.  You have to tell it by overriding `.ToString()` on that object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override [ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx) since the default implementation only returns the namespace and class name. I have provided you with an example on how you could override `ToString` here:

```
public class elementDO
{
    public int AtomicNumber { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal AtomicWeight { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"AtomicNumber: {AtomicNumber}. Symbol: {Symbol}. Name: {Name}. AtomicWeight: {AtomicNumber}";
    }
}
```

Your code together with the above mentioned implementation of `ToString` would give the output:

`AtomicNumber: 1. Symbol: H. Name: Hydrogen. AtomicWeight: 1`

Comment: Thank you, this was unclear to me before and I was having a lot of trouble finding a solution.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment suggested, when you're creating a custom class, you should override the default [ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
// I would change the class name to ElementDO in order to be consist with .NET Naming Conventions
public class elementDO
{
    public int AtomicNumber { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal AtomicWeight { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", AtomicNumber, Symbol, AtomicWeight, Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip on .NET naming, I am trying to refine my practices.

Comment: Then i would suggest you to have a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For starters, whoever down voted this question should be shot. This is a fantastic question.

The answer lies in what you're implying from your Console.WriteLine() statement. This method takes a string. That method infers from elements[1] to means "elements[1].ToString()". Since you've not overridden the object.ToString() method, the default output is what you get - a rather meaningless namespace and object name.

There are really two answers to this problem. As suggested, you can provide an override within your object to give it a default output. The other option is to be more specific what you sent to Console.WriteLine(), such as:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({1}), elements[1].Name, elements[1].Symbol));
```

The console output would look like this:

> Hydrogen (H)

Comment: Upvote for a great example for an alternative solution!

Comment: Thanks as well, I'm glad to know all possible methods!.

Comment: Console.WriteLine has an overload for string formatting, just so you know.